# Search an id and place data corresponding to that id in the same page using codeigniter and ajax.the data cannot place to the fields

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

the data corresponding to the id is getting.but cannot place to the text fields.
i want to place data corresponding to that id in the text fields.anybody can help.its not getting
Controller

```
 public function addrfqoffline() {
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->view('moderator/templates/header');
        $this->load->view('moderator/templates/sidebar');
        $rid=$this->input->post('reqid');
         echo $rid;
      $requirement=$this->requirement_model->viewdata($rid);
      $data['customers']=$this->userdata->usersname();
        $data['merchants']=$this->merchant_model->merchantname();
       // $data['mroproducts']=$this->mroproduct_model->mroproductname();
        $data['units']=$this->requirement_model->fetchunits();

        if($requirement)
      {
           foreach ($requirement as $reqdata) {
                $dat['reqid'] = $reqdata->rqm_id;
                $dat['service'] = $reqdata->rqm_service;
               $this->load->view('moderator/mrorfqnew',array_merge($dat,$data));
           }

      }
        $this->load->view('moderator/mrorfq',$data);
            $this->load->view('moderator/templates/footer');
}
```

view

```
   <div class="col-xs-6">
        <label for="txtname">Title of Quotation Request :</label>
        <input type="text" name="txtTitle" class="form-control" id="txtname"  value="<?php if(!empty($reqid)){echo $reqid;} ?>" required>
   </div>`enter code here`
```

model

```
public function viewdata($reqid) {
      $this->db -> select('*');
        $this -> db -> from('jil_requirements');
    $this -> db -> where('rqm_id',$reqid);
    $query = $this -> db -> get();
         return $query->result();
}
```

ajax

```
<script>
function getValue(val) {
  //alert(val);
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url()?>moderator/RFQ/addrfqoffline",
    data:'reqid='+val,
    success: function(data){
             alert(data);
        $("#txtproduct").html(data);
    }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: where is the ajax code??

Comment: <script>
function getValue(val) {
  //alert(val);
 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "<?php echo base_url()?>moderator/RFQ/addrfqoffline",
 data:'reqid='+val,
 success: function(data){
             alert(data);
  $("#txtproduct").html(data);
 }
 });
}
</script>

Comment: add in your question. and are you getting any errors in console??

Comment: what is alert giving??

Comment: when clicking on the search button the textbox value is getting and that is getting in the controller action. but the corresponding data is not getting in textbox

Comment: What us alert showing??

Comment: alert just showing codes in the view file. and when i echo the id in the controller. id is also printing in the alert

Comment: what ever coming in alert is correct??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97160/discussion-between-angel-and-niranjan-n-raju).

Comment: yes id getting is correct

Comment: did the answer helped you??

Comment: sure dearr. thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create an empty div in the page where you want to display the content.

```
 <div id="content"></div>
```

Next, change your controller function like this

```
function addrfqoffline() {
    $content = "";
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $content = $this->load->view('moderator/templates/header','',true);
    $content .= $this->load->view('moderator/templates/sidebar','',true);
    $rid = $this->input->post('reqid');        
    $requirement = $this->requirement_model->viewdata($rid);
    $data['customers'] = $this->userdata->usersname();
    $data['merchants'] = $this->merchant_model->merchantname();
    // $data['mroproducts']=$this->mroproduct_model->mroproductname();
    $data['units'] = $this->requirement_model->fetchunits();

    if ($requirement) {
        foreach ($requirement as $reqdata) {
            $dat['reqid'] = $reqdata->rqm_id;
            $dat['service'] = $reqdata->rqm_service;
            $content .= $this->load->view('moderator/mrorfqnew', array_merge($dat, $data),true);
        }
    }
    $content .= $this->load->view('moderator/mrorfq', $data,true);
    $content .= $this->load->view('moderator/templates/footer',true);
    echo $content;// this will echo the view here
}
```

Now in ajax success,

```
success: function(data){
    $("#content").html(data);
}
```

This should help you.